# How can I refactor a set of ugly if statements?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have this set of If statements which work fine but just looks a little ugly. Is there any way I can tart it up instead of using big ole' ugly if statements? The problem is that it uses string.contains which makes it a bit difficult to implement a dictionary, which I tried and failed :(

Here it is:

```
foreach (var Item in Stuff)
            {
                var loweredQuoteItem = quoteItem.Name.ToLower();

                if (loweredQuoteItem.Contains("one"))
                    Item.InsurerNameShort = "Item One";

                if (loweredQuoteItem.Contains("two"))
                    Item.InsurerNameShort = "Item Two";

                if (loweredQuoteItem.Contains("chaucer"))
                    Item.InsurerNameShort = "Chaucer";

                if (loweredQuoteItem.Contains("three"))
                    Item.InsurerNameShort = "Item Three";

                if (loweredQuoteItem.Contains("four"))
                    Item.InsurerNameShort = "Item Four";

                if (loweredQuoteItem.Contains("five"))
                    Item.InsurerNameShort = "Item Five";

               }
```

Comment: For starters, this should be if/else if to eliminate redundant checks.  Other than that, this is probably going to be as good as it gets.

Comment: Is this an if/else situation?  It seems like a string containing both "one" and "two" would both be executed.

Comment: @adv12 This would be closed as "hypothetical code" on Code Review. Additionally, it is a specific question which doesn't necessarily make it off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is having an array of words ("one", "two", "chaucer", etc.), looping over that array, checking for contains and capitalizing the starting letter an option?

Comment: You should be able to use a Dictionary with "one", "two", "chaucer" ... as the key values & "Item One", "Item Two", "Chaucer" ... as the values. Iterate through the key values & as soon as you get a match return the value. Examples in the docs : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that it uses string.contains which makes it a bit difficult to implement a dictionary, which I tried and failed :(

Then I guess you implemented it incorrectly. Here's what you should do:

- Construct a Dictionary.
- Put "Item One" as value for key "one"
- Put "Item Two" as value for key "two"
- Put "Item Two" as value for key "chaucer"
- etc...
- Inside your current loop, once you have the `loweredQuoteItem`, loop over your Dictionary.

  - If dictionary contains `innerLoopKey`, set `Item.InsurerNameShort` to `innerLoopValue` (and optionally break)

Make sure to construct this Dictionary outside of your `foreach (var Item in Stuff)` loop, for better performance.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify your method you can use inner Action. In this way your method will be looking like this

```
        Action<string,string, Action> method = (source, search, action) => {if (source.Contains(search)) action(); };
        method(loweredQuoteItem, "one", () => Item.InsurerNameShort = "Item One");
        method(loweredQuoteItem, "two", () => Item.InsurerNameShort = "Item Two");
        method(loweredQuoteItem, "chaucer", () => Item.InsurerNameShort = "Item Chaucer");
```

If without lambda and your logic is really so simple then you can move your IF statement inside different method:

```
    public void SetValueIfContains(string source, string search, string value, MyClass item)
    {
        if (source.Contains(search))
        {
            item.InsurerNameShort = value;
        }
    }

    public void YourFunction()
    {
        var loweredQuoteItem = quovteItem.Name.ToLower();
        SetValueIfContains(loweredQuoteItem, "one", "Item One", Item);
        SetValueIfContains(loweredQuoteItem, "two", "Item Two", Item);
        SetValueIfContains(loweredQuoteItem, "Chaucer", "Item chaucer", Item);
    }
```

If logic inside `IF` statement will be complex your can define `ISrategy` interface and implement strategies for each case. It is more best practice.

Comment: I would not use this method as it uses a lambda with a side-effect. (Nothing wrong with that per-se, just not best practice IMO)